# No Outlets or Actions showing up in file's owner

Tags: ios, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

In my Xcode project, I have a .xib file, but none of my actions or outlets are showing up in the file's owner.

They were all showing up normally just a second ago, but now they're gone. I didn't change or add any code at all. This all happened after I closed (not force quit) Xcode then re-opened it.

Any ideas? Again, it was working fine just a second ago, and my File's owner is still a NSObject (as default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please elaborate as to what you mean by "it was working already" ? Is the file owner of your .xib a custom class of yours?

If that's the case, did you set the Custom Class properly for your .xib (Utilities -> Identity Inspector -> Custom Class -> `<MyCustomClassName>`) like this

[image]

Comment: Wow... I never actually thought of replacing the file's owner class with RootViewController. Must have gotten erased somehow. Thanks a bunch!